# How to replay boss battles?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I need to get the "Point Counter-Point" achievement which requires me to do the Deathstroke battle without missing a single counter. I have already beaten the game and the New Game Plus mode, though, and I am at the Deathstroke battle in the I am the Night mode.

Without the counter icons it is nearly impossible to do this battle in I am the Night mode (plus, I won't know if I even missed a counter and didn't realize it). If I don't get the achievement when I do the battle in this mode, how do I go back and replay the Deathstroke battle to get the achievement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no active way to replay boss fights in Batman: Arkham Origins. Confirmed on [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/app/209000/discussions/0/792924952685381965/?l=czech), and on GameFAQs, [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/710575-batman-arkham-origins/67625072) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/710576-batman-arkham-origins/67626320).

It is even confirmed on [TrueAchievements](http://www.trueachievements.com/a180204/point-counterpoint-achievement.htm#) as a missable achievement, meaning that if you do not unlock the achievement when it is open to you, there is no going back to retry.

> **[MustangNox](http://www.trueachievements.com/MustangNox.htm) has some good advice for handling the boss fight, in terms of making it easier to unlock this achievement.**
>
> *I though this missable achievement was going to be quite hard, but after a few tries I found a method that works well. All you have to do is jump over Deathstroke using AA, kick him once with X and then AA jump again. Also, every few hits (8 without upgrades) you will have an effective B+Y combo available to use.
> This way, you need to press Y to counter only during QTEs. It's even possible to finish the fight without Deathstroke throwing barrels at you (that's what happened to me).*

Comment: Ah, okay. That's a stupid design flaw, and one of the reasons Arkham Origins frustrates me so much. Thanks for the advice also, but I've read that already and it only makes it /slightly/ easier on I Am The Night. I guess maybe I'll reset my entire game after I get all the other achievements and then go back and get that one,